# Reading data without headers in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, header

I would like to know how to read a .txt file with Python, so that I can plot the data.

The file is this form:

```
1. " Experiment 1 1 1
2.   Date: 04/04/18
3.   data A B C
4.  1 12.5 0 3
5.  2 13 1 4.6
6.  3 14 10 5
7.  . . . .
  . . . .        "
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And then add your best not-working attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt', sep=' ', skiprows=3, names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

If you do not want to add column names on import

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt', sep=' ', skiprows=3, header=None)
```